# Azure WebApp FTP not updating

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I've published a web app through FTP in Azure WebApps and it worked fine, but now when I open the FTP client in Windows Explorer and replace the index.html file and restart the web app, my changes are not reflected and the former version of index.html is still the one being presented.

Does Azure WebApp have a delay to reflect changes in `wwwroot`?

There is just one index.html file in `wwwroot` and it is also the first item in the Default Documents list in the Configure Tab.

Comment: I have the same issue. Not all the time, but sometime the FTP view and the website are not aligned.

Comment: Same issue, i've tried stopping app service plan, renaming the default file to intentionally 'break' the site, accessing in different browsers with no cached content etc, the default original content persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used web apps for some time now and never had the issue you are experiencing. Perhaps the best thing to do is intentionally break the site by removing the index.html file altogether, restart the site then navigate to it. Obviously it will fail (Well it should fail!). Then try uploading the new index.html file, restart the site and see what you get.